# My .exe is missing some .dlls, even though I made the crucial settings for it to embed all the dlls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I recently finished a project of mine and want to give it to a friend, but he can't run it due to missing dlls.

I then adjusted my project according to some guides on SO, I adjusted my build process to "Embedded Ressources" and so on, but it just won't work. Also, I added my 2 dlls as Ressources in my project properties.

However, when I manually give him the 2 dlls I use and he pastes them into the folder containing the .exe, it will run as expected.

I should also note that the .exe actually seems to contain the dlls, as the .exe without dlls is just like 20KB big, while the size after my changes is pretty much the sum of the 20KB plus the size of my dlls.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Resources are not intended to be used for that purpose and of course the program cannot find the DLL required. If your goal is to have just one file to distribute you need to use a tool like [ILMERGE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx), by the way can you link the _guides on SO_ that you have used?

Answer (score 0):

You should add all satellite assemblies (i.e. ***.dll***) to your project references, thus they will be copied to your output path (for example `\bin\debug\`) as part of regular build.